# post csv rows and delete them once posted

Tags: python, api, csv, request

I've got a raspberry pi with a thermocouple writing rows of temperature data to two csv's: A local one for the pi, and a `data_queue` csv. I then have another script that runs as a separate daemon process is supposed to consume the content of the data_queue csv and make a post request with each row to an api. In order to avoid duplicates, I want to remove each row of the queue csv that is posted to the api. I have the following code:

```py
def post(root):
    headers = []
    sent = []                               # this will contain every line that is sent to the api
    
    with open(root+'/data_queue.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        request_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        headers = next(reader)                  # grab headers
        for line in reader:                     # loop over lines in csv
            payload = {}                        # make a payload dict with the headers as keys and the values as the line content
            sent.append(line)
            for i in range(len(headers)):       # fill the payload
                if i == 0 or i == 1 or i == 3:  # convert data to its appropriate type
                    line[i] = int(line[i])
                if i == 5 or i == 6 or i == 7:
                    try:
                        line[i] = float(line[i])
                    except ValueError as m:     # correction and uncertainty are filled as 'None' until we actually calibrate the thermos
                        logger.warning('{}: No data was found for {}'.format(m, headers[i]))
                        line[i] = 0
                        
                payload.update( {headers[i]: line[i]} )
                
            # convert the dict to json, and make a post request to the api
            response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.67:5000/new_row', headers=request_headers, data = json.dumps(payload))
            status = response.status_code
            logger.debug('{}: sent'.format(status) if status == 200 else '{}: failed to send'.format(status))
            
            if status == 500: # remove line from sent list if the line fails to post
                sent.pop(len(sent)-1)
    
    print(sent)
    logger.debug('starting clean')
    csv_cleanup(root, sent, headers)
    logger.debug('csv cleaned')
        
def csv_cleanup(root, sent, headers):        
    leftovers = []
    new = root+'/data_queue_edit.csv'
    old = root+'/data_queue.csv'
    
    with open(new, 'w') as out:      # create edit csv
        logger.error('made new csv')
        writer = csv.writer(out)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        logger.error('wrote headers')
        
    with open(old, 'r') as inp:      # open old csv and grab leftovers
        logger.error('opened old csv')
        reader = csv.reader(inp)
        next(reader)                 # skip headers
        for old_row in reader:
            leftovers.append(old_row)
            for new_row in sent:     # compare old csv and all sent rows, if dt's match up then remove it from leftovers
                
                if old_row[2] == new_row[2]:
                    leftovers.pop(leftovers.index(old_row))
                    logger.error('removed {}'.format(new_row))

    with open(new, 'a') as out:      # append leftovers to new csv
        logger.error('appending to new csv')
        writer = csv.writer(out)
        for row in leftovers:
            logger.error('writing {}'.format(row))
            writer.writerow(row)
            
    os.remove(old)
    os.rename(new, old)             # replace old csv with new csv
    logger.error('renamed file')
```

Although this works, if there is every a situation where the raspberry pi adds move data to the queue csv after its been posted but before its been cleaned, then I will be loosing said data. Is there any work around this besides timing my scripts to clean the queue in sync to avoid loosing data?

Comment: Why don't you upload a new json/csv file for each new record, then have the consuming application delete that file after it is processed? That way you won't run into problems with both applications trying to get a lock on the file?

Comment: Just tried this and got it working, I can't seem to spot any flaws where data would be lost. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!